# Custom definition of \ref causes problem inside argument of \caption

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, ref

I am trying to implement a custom version of the `\ref` command. I found out that in order for me being able to redefine this command I need to do so via `\AtBeginDocument` as otherwise my change seemed to get overwritten by something else.

It works now as expected except when using `\ref` inside a `\caption` which will produce the following error:

```
Argument of \@caption has an extra }. \caption{Test here \ref{sec:Section}}
Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete. \caption{Test here \ref{sec:Section}}
```

Here is a MWE reproducing the problem:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xstring}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\refCopy\ref
    \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
        \IfBeginWith{#1}{eq:}{
            (\refCopy{#1})
        }{
        \refCopy{#1}
    }
}
}

\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section}
    \label{sec:Section}

    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Test here \ref{sec:Section}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If I remove my custom implementation of `\ref` the document compiles just fine.

What is causing this problem and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Add `\protect` before your `\ref`.

Comment: Off-topic: Since it's conventional to always typeset equation numbers -- even in cross-references -- using the upright font shape, you should probably change `(\refCopy{#1})` to `{\upshape(\refCopy{#1})}`. That way, if a cross-reference to an equation happens to occur in a stretch of text that's otherwise rendered in italics (e.g., in the body of a theorem-like environment), the cross-referenced equation number will still be typeset using the upright font.

Comment: Also, you could just use \thesection instead of \ref{sec:section}.

Comment: @JohnKormylo yeah I know... The posted code was just a quick, dirty example that reproduced my problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your (re)definition of `\ref` makes it a so-called "fragile" command. This matters if `\ref` is used in the argument of a "moving command" -- such as `\caption`. You need to change

```
\caption{Test here \ref{sec:Section}}
```

to

```
\caption{Test here \protect\ref{sec:Section}}
```

Moreover, you need to make sure that no spurious whitespace is introduced before or after the cross-referencing call-out. I suggest you change

```
    \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
        \IfBeginWith{#1}{eq:}{
            (\refCopy{#1})
        }{
        \refCopy{#1}
    }
}
```

to

```
    \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
        \IfBeginWith{#1}{eq:}{%
            (\refCopy{#1})%
        }{%
        \refCopy{#1}%
    }%
}%
```

Can you spot the six new instances of `%`?

---

*Addendum*: As @AlanMunn has pointed out in a comment, the `\protect` directives aren't needed if one loads the `etoolbox` package and replaces `\renewcommand{\ref}...` with `\renewrobustcmd{\ref}...`.

Formatting the code as

```
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
  \IfBeginWith{#1}{eq:}{%
    (\refCopy{#1})%
  }{%
    \refCopy{#1}%
  }%
}%
```

may make it more readable, as the levels are more evident.

Comment: Alternatively, load `etoolbox` and use `\renewrobustcmd` instead in the redefinition, then `\protect` isn't needed.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Thanks for this. I've edited my answer to feature your comment more prominently.

Comment: By the way, since the code is inside `\AtBeginDocument`, also the final brace pertaining to `\renewcommand` should be followed by `%`. Usually LaTeX is in vertical mode when it evaluates the `\AtBeginDocument` token list, but one never knows.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for pointing out this issue. I've edited the answer to provide a sixth addtional `%` character...